# Stop AWS OpenSearch service temporarily for cost savings

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

I am looking at doing some cost savings in AWS and want to know if we can stop and then start the AWS Opensearch service for a couple of days.

My scenario is that the application which uses the OpenSearch service (Elasticsearch) remains down during 2 days every week... During this time OpenSearch remains active and incurs costs...

I know one option to save the costs is to downgrade the node type and reduce the number of nodes during the application downtime.

But let me know if there are any other options where I can entirely "Switch Off" and "Switch On" the service just like we can do with EC2 instances.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to stop the cluster today. What I have seen to reduce bill was that team edited the cluster to reduce the instance type to a t2.small  (or smaller ones) instance which is significantly cheaper than the previous instance.

Then when they needed to resume testing they changed the instance type back to what they required.

One other thing maybe is to take a [snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-snapshots.html) of your domain, the disable Opensearch for the weekend. Finally restore it back on monday with the snapshot you got.

Comment: I like the idea of the snapshot... Since it has an hourly snapshot configuration it should be easier... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

AWS launched OpenSearch Serverless during reInvent 2022 but still in preview.
This is the ideal solution which would not require you manage clusters.

https://aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/features/serverless/

Until then, go for downsizing the instance during non peak hours.

**[Edit]:** It is GA now as on 25th Jan 2023

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/amazon-opensearch-serverless-is-now-generally-available/

Comment: the pricing on Opensearch serverless is not clear. Would I pay if I'm not using it, not sure to be honest. Let's see.

Comment: @brushtakopo Pay per use, meaning only pay when you use

Comment: right, so are they gonna stop it to not incur OCU cost, how much time it would take to bring them back. As I said, let's see when it get GA.

Comment: I am curious what instance type the opensearch serverless use? I would love to see Graviton (C6g) under the hood powering the serverless.